# How to position two divs side by side where the second width is 100%?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this:

```
width=60px         width = remaining space
|------|    |-----------------------------------|
| div1 |    | Loren ipsun...                    |
|------|    |                                   |
            |                            div2   |
            |-----------------------------------|
```

> **[Sample html on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2yBZa/)**

Is it possible to place two divs side-by-side leaving the second div with all remaining space?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just float the first div, and set the margin-left of the second div to accommodate the width of the first div. Something like this:

```
div.one {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}

div.two {
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Keep in mind that the `width` CSS property on the div only applies to the content, so you need to set the `margin-left` to be the sum of the `width`, `border`, `margin`, and `padding` properties of the first div.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2yBZa/15/) is the updated version of your jsfiddle. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: I was using `display: inline-block`. I guess this was messing up. This works, thank you.

Comment: Just be careful with those two divs and don't add padding or borders to them. If you must put containers in them.

Comment: @nux: I tried to address your concern in the question: "accommodate the width **(including padding, margins, border)** of the first div"

Comment: @nux: I edited my answer to try to make this more clear. Let me know if you still find it ambiguous.

Comment: this is bad, you need to use float left and float right only to put 2 divs side by side

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it will be done :

```
.image {
background:green;
color:green;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
width:60px;
}

.content {
background:blue;
color:white;
margin-left:60px;
   }
```

Comment: You need to remove the `width:100%;` from `.content`, otherwise it'll make the content block the size of the viewport, causing the total width of all content to be greater than the viewport, so a horizontal scrollbar will appear.

Comment: when you use absolute positon, you should set its parent div's position to relative for IE7.

Comment: the absolute positioning is also dangerous since we don't know the context in which it will be used. this *should* be fine so long as it's placed at the top of the page or within a relatively positioned block, but otherwise it could behave unexpectedly. You really don't need it to be absolutely positioned at all. It doesn't add much value here.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

CSS:

```
#container { background: silver; width: 100% }


.image
{
    background: green; color: green;
    width: 60px; height: 60px;
    float: left;

}
.content
{
    background: blue; color: white;
   margin-left: 60px;


}
```

And on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/2yBZa/24/) (It's playing up at the moment)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Tabla de contenidos - Template</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { 
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        #divleft{
            width: 60px;
            float: left;
        }
        #divright{
            display: block;
            margin-left: 62px;
        }
</style> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divleft">This DIV has a width of 60px.</div>
    <div id="divright" >This DIV occupies the rest of the page...</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The 62px margin is to avoid overlap the 1 extra px of each border.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use the [flexible box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

this working proposal is supported in recent firefox, chrome, and safari.

it can be ported to unsupported browsers using [flexie.js.](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie)

Answer (score 0):

there is new way to arrange elements whit CSS3
Check here this page [Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/), a game where you help Froggy and friends by writing CSS code!

Guide this frog to the lilypad on the right by using the justify-content property, which aligns items horizontally and accepts the following values:

- **flex-start**: Items align to the left side of the container.
- **flex-end**: Items align to the right side of the container.
- **center**: Items align at the center of the container.
- **space-between**: Items display with equal spacing between them.
- **space-around**: Items display with equal spacing around them.