# Contents in the float div overflow issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I encountered a problem about float style. Like the html code below:

```
...
<body>
    <div style="float:left;width:25%;height:100px;background-color:red;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:74%;height:100px;border:1px solid black;">
        <div style="width:1000px;height:50px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
...
```

The effect is that the content in the 2th float div overflow. 
Yellow div is in the float div, but its width exceeds its parent's. 
I want to know how to set the css style to make the 2th float div can suite its child element's width/height automatically?
I know clear style can clear the float of divs listed by order, but how to handle it when it contains a larger child?
I don't want to use js to modify parent div's width.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `min-height` and `min-width`. This way the parent will always fit the children's height and width when they are bigger.

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bws1m0w/1/).

Answer (score 0):

By removing `width` and `height` property (or setting `min-heigh` and `min-width` property as [Stephan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843321/contents-in-the-float-div-overflow-issue/27843906#27843906) you will made parent div to stretch over child.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohtx2nc/1/

This however cause that if they are wider than screen second floated div will move to next row

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohtx2nc/

If you insist on having two divs one next to another you will need to do some tricks like in [How to position two divs side by side where the second width is 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328336/how-to-position-two-divs-side-by-side-where-the-second-width-is-100)

http://jsfiddle.net/5ohtx2nc/3/